# Multiple Left Joins in the same query causes "Invalid Operation" Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the following queries ...

Query #1

```
SELECT aa.DocNum, b.QualityClass
FROM dbo_TransferHistory AS aa LEFT JOIN PCQualityClass AS bb ON aa.DocNum = bb.DocumentNum
WHERE (((aa.DocNum)=[Enter Doc Num]));
```

Query #2

```
SELECT aa.DocNum, bb.QualityClass, cc.BldgCond
FROM (dbo_TransferHistory AS aa LEFT JOIN PCQualityClass AS bb ON aa.DocNum = bb.DocumentNum) 
      LEFT JOIN PCBldgCond AS cc ON aa.DocNum = cc.DocumentNum
WHERE (((aa.DocNum)=[Enter Doc Num]));
```

dbo_TransferHistory is an table I access through an ODBC connector.
PCQualityClass and PCBldgCond are two queries that are based off another ODBC table.  Both of these queries have only the two respective fields referenced in the main query.

DocNum and DocumentNum are the same type ("Short Text" and a length of 12) and while I would like to make the names the same, I cannot.
When the query is run, an Inputbox pops up and [Enter Doc Num] is replaced with the Document Number I want the data for.

The queries were created in Access using the Create Query tool.

The problem is that while Query #1 will work, Query #2 causes the error "Invalid Operation".

Changing to inner joins will allow Query #2 to function but will cause issues as there are times that one or both of the two sub queries do not have data but I still need the data from the primary table.

Please help, I am at my wits end as to why this is not working.  Is this an Access 2013 bug that will not allow for two Left Joins in the same query or something else I am missing?

Comment: If you remove `PCQualityClass` from query #2, does it work then?

Comment: Yes.  Running #2 with only the PCBldgCond join works.  I have tried with other queries as the right side of the join as well.  When there is only one join, everything is fine.  Add a second join and Access kicks the "Invalid Operation" error.

Comment: I have the same issue. I was trying to join from the same column on the left in both joins to different tables (actually saved Access queries) on the right. I tried making the column on the left appear twice in its table and joining from each one only once, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is frustrating the absolute !@#$% out of me.  The syntax is correct and everything I see online says it should work.  Out of pure frustration and some curiosity, I imported the ODBC tables into Access as local tables and changed the table references in the queries to use the local tables. OMG, now it works.  Same data, same structure, different table type, and it !@#$ing works.  So it looks like the problem is in attempting to make multiple joins using ODBC.  Unfortunately, I cannot create local tables from the ODBC every time this query gets run.  Going to keep looking into this and see if I can find another workaround.  Any other ideas?

Basically, Access will not allow multiple Outer Joins when using ODBC data sources.  I am going to mark this as answered and rephrase the question in a new post.
Thank you.

Comment: It may be possible to do some of this work using make table queries which is a bit quicker than reimporting the ODBC data from source. In my case I had 3 access queries and I was bringing them together in one master query which did an outer join from query 1 to query 2 and an outer join from query 1 to query 3. There's no good reason for that not to work and if I added criteria to ensure there were no nulls in query 3 it worked, but failed if I left the outer joins including nulls which is kinda the point of an outer join. I had to make both query2 and query 3 into local tables.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL looks like it should work, so the problem is probably the combination of the base queries plus the two left joins.

My general experience with Access queries on ODBC tables and with multiple outer joins is: even if you get them to work, they usually perform pretty badly.

So my suggestion is: Re-create the whole thing as **view** on SQL Server, and link that view. Then your Access query becomes something trivial like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo_ViewTransferHistory
WHERE DocNum=[Enter Doc Num]
```

Comment: That would be nice but I have no ability to edit the server side data.  I can only get at it through Access.